# Batch file for all of domain

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe

Is there a way i can make a batch file to push out to all of my domain for example something like this

```
powercfg -h off
```

How would I set that up to run over a domain?

Maybe even over PowerShell if possible?

Comment: How about putting that in your Domain Controller's sysvol in the scripts directory as a `.cmd` batch file and have each user you need it to apply to point to that batch script as a login script via active directory https://www.petri.com/setting-up-logon-script-through-active-directory-users-computers-windows-server-2008 ... I'd use sysvol tho if possible so `\\domainname\sysvol` should take you there... you'd obviously want to test this with a test account that is not a local admin on one of the machines (or per OS) that'll need it applied... Quick thought only

Comment: there's also a powerconfig GPO element which you could use